# How to make a collection of two models grouped by date in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two models `Tour` and `Adventure`. I want to make a group of both tours and adventures grouped by date. And display it like this:

July 17

Tour 1 Tour 2 Tour 3
Adventure 1 Adventure 2 Adventure 3

July 16

Tour 1 Tour 2 Tour 3
Adventure 1 Adventure 2 Adventure 3

I know how to make the grouping of a single model. It goes like this:

```
Tour::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(20)->get()->groupBy(function($item)
          {
            return $item->created_at->format('d-M-y');
          });
```

How can I join the two models and display them into a single date? With the current code day appear in different collections.

EDIT: Including the table migrations.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tours', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');

          $table->string('name', 125);
          $table->string('slug')->index();
          $table->text('description')->nullable();
          $table->string('duration')->nullable();
          $table->string('url')->nullable();

          $table->boolean('ended')->default(false)->index();

          $table->timestamps();
        });
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE tours ADD FULLTEXT search(name)');
    }
```

The migration for the adventure model is the same as the tour. The two models does not share a relationship between them.

Comment: You probably need to do a join between the 2 tables. Could you share the table-definitions with us? Then we can show you how a join should look like.

Comment: @RobBiermann I will include the table migrations in the question. The two models does not share a relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your looking for the merge() method for merging two collection [laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-merge](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-merge)

```
        //Get all Tours
        $tours= Tour::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        //Get all adventures
        $adventures= Adventure::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

        //Merge both collection into 1 single collection and group according the date
        $dates= $tours->merge($adventures)->groupBy(function($item) {
            return $item->created_at->format('d-M-y');
        });

        return view('someView', compact('dates'));
```

And then you can loop within the date

```
        @foreach($dates as $date => $activity)
            <h2>{{$date}}</h2>
            <li>
                {{$activity}}
            </li>
        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
Tour::join('adventures', DB::raw('date(adventures.created_at)'), '=', DB::raw('date(tours.created_at)'))->get()
```

Ofcourse you still have options like grouping or ordering before running the `->get()`, as the `->get()` executed the query and makes your collection :)